# finding numbers with spaces using regex

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, numbers, whitespace

I need to use regex_count in Oracle SQL (no `\b` available)
 and I need to count values (in format `(\d{1,}[a-zA-Z]{0,2})` (like `123`, `123a`, `34bc`, but not `32abc`) in a string which are separated from each other (or other noises) by at least one space, so example

```
'34 64 84' - should count to 3
'34 fh84h d88f 34 ' - should count to 2
'a54. 374 4/5' - should count 1
'5,5' - should count 0
'10a' - should count 1
'20g 32lf 43vnd kf34ld' - count 2
'9A_10' - counts 0
```

Something like that.

`(^|\s|\b)(\d{1,}[a-zA-Z]{0,2})($|\s)` - but these is no `\b` in Oracle SQL and anyway I am not sure if it works.

Anyone with suggestions?

Comment: Try `SELECT REGEXP_COUNT(' ' ||  REGEXP_REPLACE('a54. 374 4/5', '(\s)', '\1 ') || ' ',  '(^|\s)\d+[a-zA-Z]{0,2}($|\s)') FROM DUAL`

Comment: Hi. It seems to work. I will check tomorrow with database. But I want to learn - please educate. Please teach me master

Answer (score 4):

I suggest duplicating each whitespace and add leading/trailing spaces and then run a simple `(^|\s)<YOUR_PATTERN>($|\s)` pattern:

```
SELECT REGEXP_COUNT(' ' ||  REGEXP_REPLACE('a54. 374 4/5', '(\s)', '\1 ') || ' ',  '(^|\s)\d+[a-zA-Z]{0,2}($|\s)') FROM DUAL
```

**Details**

- `' ' ||`  - adding a leading space
- `REGEXP_REPLACE('a54. 374 4/5', '(\s)', '\1 ')` - match and capture any whitespace and replace with itself plus a space
- `|| ' '` - adding a trailing space.

Now, your count will be correct when running a  `(^|\s)\d+[a-zA-Z]{0,2}($|\s)` regex (note that `+` is equal to `{1,}`).

- `(^|\s)` - start of string, whitespace
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `[a-zA-Z]{0,2}` - 0 to 2 letters
- `($|\s)` - end of string or whitespace.

Comment: Ok. I see - I had the problem with one space - but now I see how it was solved :-)  Thanks for explaining

Comment: Really THANKS.  :-)

Comment: Is it possible without duplicating each whitespace?  I am using variable VARCHAR2(500) as later I need to extract the value if I find only one value in a record (count =1). So, when duplicating each whitespace having let say 499 char long text in variable then the varchar2 will be exploited - right? If yes then is it possible to do that without duplicating whitespaces?

Comment: @Zbigniew It is not possible with a regex then, because 1) Oracle regex does not support lookarounds, 2) there is no word boundary support.